# How do you use the JRuby gem file

Tags: jruby

In the [JRuby download](http://jruby.org/download) page there is a `JRuby-jars 9.1.5.0 .gem` file. How do you use this file?

Comment: Check the [usage documentation](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/tree/master/maven/jruby-jars).